# Quotient group $S^3/\{+I,-I\}$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

How can I prove that the quotient group $S^3/\{+I,-I\}$ is isomorphic to $SO_3$ and that the group $S^3$ is not isomophic to $SO_3$?

Here $S^3$ is the subgroup of the quaternion group: $S^3=\{a+bi+cj+dk | a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\}$

Comment: What do you mean by $S^3/\{\pm I\}$? Are you looking at the orbit space of $S^3$ under the action of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ given by the antipodal map?

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $S^3/\pm 1$ is isomorphic to $SO(3)$, use the [hypersphere of rotations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#The_hypersphere_of_rotations) This gives a way of naturally thinking of $SO(3)$ as a quotient of $S^3$. Embedding everything inside the quaternions makes defining the mapping much cleaner.

To show that $SO(3)$ and $S^3$ are not isomorphic as lie groups, note that this gives a homeomorphism of the underlying topological spaces. But from the hypersphere of rotations, one can also see that $SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{RP}^3$ are homeomorphic, and $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{RP}^3) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, whereas $\pi_{1}(S^3) = \{1\}$ since the $3$-sphere is simply connected.

Comment: They are also not isomorphic as groups.  $S^3$ has nontrivial center ($-1$ is in it), but the center of $SO(3)$ is trivial.